# How to turn on Solenoid based on Soil Moisture value?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am powering solenoid with 24 volt as required however I am using TIP122

transistor that has base connected to Arduino Digital Pin 6 via a 1K Resistor. 
And the collector is connected to negative side of 1N4001 diode, this also serves as the Negative out for solenoid. and emitter is connected to the 24 volt power input.
The positive input from power source is connected to positive terminal of diode is directly connected to solenoid.

[image]

As per the logic I am trying to turn on Solenoid based on Signal from Arduino PIN 6, but for some reason Solenoid doesnt power up.

In my code below I want to turn on solenoid if soil moisture goes above 60. the signal is coming from Pin 6 but solenoid doesnt power up.

```
#include <SPI.h>

int solenoidPin = 6;    //This is the output pin on the Arduino we are using

int GLED = 5; // Wet Soil Indicator at Digital PIN D5
int RLED = 9; // Dry Soil Indicator at Digital PIN D9
int SENSE = 1; // Soil Sensor input at Analog PIN A1
int val = 0;

int greenLedPin = 2; // LED on pin 2
int yellowLedPin = 3;
int redLedPin = 4;

int lightSensorPin = A0;
int analogValue = 0;



void setup() {
  pinMode(solenoidPin, OUTPUT);           //Sets the pin as an output

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(greenLedPin, OUTPUT); // LED on pin 2
  pinMode(yellowLedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLedPin, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(GLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RLED, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  val = analogRead(SENSE);
  val = val / 10;
  analogValue = analogRead(lightSensorPin);
  Serial.print("LDR value: ");
  Serial.print(analogValue);
  digitalWrite (redLedPin, analogValue < 55) ;
  digitalWrite (yellowLedPin, analogValue >= 55 && analogValue <= 100) ;
  digitalWrite (greenLedPin, analogValue > 100) ;

  Serial.print(" Soil Moisture: ");
  Serial.println(val);
  digitalWrite(GLED, (val < 50));
  digitalWrite(RLED, (val > 50));
  // Turn on Solenoid Valve if soil moisture value greater than 60
  digitalWrite(solenoidPin, (val > 60));

}
```

I am doubting on the diode to use , because I am  powering solenoid of 24 volt and not sure if the diode is correct , as per my knowledge, diode can get direct if higher voltage is passed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe connect it to pin 6 instead of to pin 4?

Comment: Also 24V on Vin is pretty big voltage. Power regulator might be (and it will be) overheating.

Comment: Sorry ignore power input shown in image above as I mention sources of power are different for solenoid and Arduino Vin is not connected to anything

Comment: Determine whether it's a problem with your code or a problem with your circuit by connecting the yellow wire to the 5v output of the Arduino - see whether the solenoid actuates.

Comment: @MarkSmith I have added updated Fritzing as per the code .  With above circuit solenoid is getting 3.4 volts whether the soil moisture sensor is dipped in water or out of water. Is TIP122 perfect for 24 Volt/3Amp input coming from power adapter

Comment: My suggestion is still the same - except for the wire colour as you changed it: break the problem into smaller parts.  Determine whether it's a problem with your code or a problem with one of your circuits by connecting the light blue wire to the 5v output of the Arduino - see whether the solenoid actuates.

Comment: @Mark Smith, +1 for breaking down in smaller parts. That way you can find and resolve problems one by one.

Comment: J Picqurd's answer is correct BUT a look at your original diagram shows it cannot  work as shown. You show a single wire between Arduino proper and output system. You MUST have two wires (minimum so that one supplies voltage relative to the other. Ground in both systems is usually joined and then the Arduino output voltage relative to ground is produced by the ARduino and "seen" by the controlled circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking your schematic and assuming that **J1** connector is not powered by your MacBook as your Arduino board, the main problem is located to the **GND** signal.

In order to have a commutation current to the **Base** of the TIP122 through the 1K resistor, you need to link the **GND** signal its **Emitter** with the **GND** signal of your Arduino board.

See a proposed schematic from **["High-Power Control: Arduino + TIP120 Transistor"](http://bildr.org/2011/03/high-power-control-with-arduino-and-tip120/)**

[image]

Comment: would it be ok, if I take power from 5volt pin of UNO and use stepup xl6009 to convert to 24 volts and power solenoid ?

Comment: O boy I used xl6009 to convert 5 volt to 24 volt and supply to solenoid with common ground as you mentioned and its working as expected